# JavaFX dynamic gridpane row height adjustment

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am currently working on a project, and I cannot find just any solution. I want a Gridpane row height to be dynamically counted from the width of one specific column inside that row. The whole Gridpane must be resizable and the rest of the available space should take another row below so the aspect ratio of that one cell is preserved according to the element inside that cell. Any ideas boys?

[click for a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmn8B.png)

```
public class GridPaneControl extends GridPane {

    private int index;
    private Label startLabel;
    private Label endLabel;

    private HBox inputCellsContainer;
    private HBox outputCellsContainer;

    private Button inputOutputNextButton;
    private Button inputOutputPreviousButton;

    public GridPaneControl() {

        setGridLinesVisible(true);
        initialization();

        ColumnConstraints cc0 = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc0.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        cc0.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);

        ColumnConstraints cc1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        ColumnConstraints cc2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        cc2.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);

        RowConstraints rc0 = new RowConstraints();
        rc0.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        rc0.setFillHeight(false);
        rc0.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        RowConstraints rc1 = new RowConstraints();
        rc1.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        rc1.setFillHeight(false);
        rc1.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        RowConstraints rc2 = new RowConstraints();
        rc2.setVgrow(Priority.NEVER);

        RowConstraints rc3 = new RowConstraints();
        rc3.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        getColumnConstraints().addAll(cc0, cc1, cc2);
        getRowConstraints().addAll(rc0, rc1, rc2, rc3);

    }

    private void initialization() {

        inputCellsContainer = new HBox(0);
        outputCellsContainer = new HBox(0);

        GridPane.setValignment(inputCellsContainer, VPos.BOTTOM);
        GridPane.setValignment(outputCellsContainer, VPos.TOP);

        inputOutputPreviousButton = new Button("<<");
        inputOutputPreviousButton.maxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        GridPane.setHgrow(inputOutputPreviousButton, Priority.NEVER);
        GridPane.setVgrow(inputOutputPreviousButton, Priority.NEVER);
        GridPane.setMargin(inputOutputPreviousButton, new Insets(5));

        inputOutputNextButton = new Button(">>");
        inputOutputNextButton.maxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        GridPane.setHgrow(inputOutputNextButton, Priority.NEVER);
        GridPane.setVgrow(inputOutputNextButton, Priority.NEVER);
        GridPane.setMargin(inputOutputNextButton, new Insets(5));

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {

            InputOutputCell cellIn = new InputOutputCell(String.format("%02X", i), Color.AQUA, 0);
            InputOutputCell cellOut = new InputOutputCell(String.format("%02X", i), Color.BEIGE, 1);
            HBox.setHgrow(cellIn, Priority.ALWAYS);
            HBox.setHgrow(cellOut, Priority.ALWAYS);

            inputCellsContainer.getChildren().add(cellIn);
            outputCellsContainer.getChildren().add(cellOut);

        }

        GridPane.setHgrow(inputCellsContainer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setHgrow(outputCellsContainer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setVgrow(inputCellsContainer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setVgrow(outputCellsContainer, Priority.ALWAYS);

        startLabel = new Label("0");
        endLabel = new Label("31");
        GridPane.setHalignment(startLabel, HPos.LEFT);
        GridPane.setHalignment(endLabel, HPos.RIGHT);

        this.add(inputOutputPreviousButton, 0, 0, 1, 2);
        this.add(inputCellsContainer, 1, 0);
        this.add(outputCellsContainer, 1, 1);
        this.add(inputOutputNextButton, 2, 0, 1, 2);
        this.add(startLabel, 1, 2);
        this.add(endLabel, 1, 2);

    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    private class InputOutputCell extends StackPane {

        @FXML
        Text text;
        @FXML
        Rectangle rectangle;

        public InputOutputCell(String text, Color color, int type) {

            setMinSize(0, 0);

            this.text = new Text(text);
            rectangle = new Rectangle();


            if (type == 0) {
                rectangle.widthProperty().bind(inputCellsContainer.widthProperty().divide(32));
                rectangle.heightProperty().bind(inputCellsContainer.widthProperty().divide(32));

            } else {

                rectangle.widthProperty().bind(outputCellsContainer.widthProperty().divide(32));
                rectangle.heightProperty().bind(outputCellsContainer.widthProperty().divide(32));

            }

            rectangle.maxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            rectangle.maxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            rectangle.setArcHeight(10);
            rectangle.setArcWidth(10);
            rectangle.setFill(color);
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

            getChildren().addAll(rectangle, this.text);

        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text.setText(text);
        }

        public String getText() {
            return this.text.getText();
        }

    }

}
```

I want cells 1,0 and 1,1 to be resizable and clearly by increasing their width the height of row 0 and 1 should not be increasing equally. If there should be any height left I want the row 3 to take it because row 2 should not grow to height at all.

Comment: You should try to explain your goal in more general terms, because you are assuming the GridPane to be the correct solution to your problem, which it might or might not be.

Comment: OK, I can try. I want a gridpane row height to be dynamically resized to 1/32 width of one of its columns. If a width of that column changes again i want a width of that row recalculate. Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

You did a fair bit of explanation (which is good) but it is complex enough to make me read 10 times, and I think I understood 70% of it. The most puzzling part is this line:

> the rest of the available space should take another row below so the aspect ratio of that one cell is preserved according to the element inside that cell.

Not sure which "cell" you are referrring to, and what you mean by keeping aspect ratio.

Now for the actual answer, I think the most obvious one that I can see is that you have given rows 0 and 1 `ALWAYS` priority for `VGrow`.

You have 3 rows that has `ALWAYS` `VGrow`, and what the `GridPane` will do is to give all children to whatever space that they preferred to have, then distribute all the "leftover" spaces to rows with `ALWAYS`. That is why the 3 gaps in your image has the same height.

Comment: Hey,
I think you understood me correctly. I was referring to those two HBoxes in cells 1,0 and 1,1. Here is the tricky part, the height of stackepanes inside the Hboxes is 1/32 of the HBox itself. So the column 1 needs to grow to width always which is good, but how to tell the rows 0 and 1 to grow only when the Height of the HBox is increasing? 
The second problem is caused by increasing the width of whole gridpane, Stackepanes in HBoxis are growing no problem, but the height of row 1 and 2 is the same.
Hope you do understand me and thanks for the previous answer.